# How can I solve this non-linear system of equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

Does anybody know how I could go about solving the following system of equations? I have as many variables as I have equations so it should be possible to find a single solution, however it is complicated by variables being multiplied by other variables and also modular arithmetic.

I need to solve for $a,b,c,x,y,z$. Constraints are that all these variables are positive integers $0$-$9$, so they each equal one of the numbers from the set $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$. Is there any way to solve this by hand without simply trying every combination?

$$\begin{align}7c + z = 4 \quad \textrm{(mod 10)}\\
7b + zc + y = 0 \quad \textrm{(mod 10)}\\
7a + zb + yc + x = 8 \quad \textrm{(mod 10)}\\
za + yb + xc = 7 \quad \textrm{(mod 10)}\\
ya + xb = 0 \quad \textrm{(mod 10)}\\
xa = 5 \quad \textrm{(mod 10)}\end{align}$$

Comment: Maybe you could start by observing that the last equation implies either $x$ or $a$ is 5, and the other is another odd number.

Comment: Work from the bottom up.  There are very limited options for $x,a$ which imply equally limited options for $y,b$

Comment: It might be expeditious to solve the equations mod $2$ and mod $5$, then piece the solutions (if any) together via Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: I would write a program.  Unless I made a mistake, there are two solutions.